# Find the smallest set group to cover all combinatory possibilities

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm making some exercises on combinatorics algorithm and trying to figure out how to solve the question below:

Given a group of 25 bits, set (choose) 15 (non-permutable and order NON matters):

```
n!/(k!(n-k)!) = 3.268.760
```

Now for every of these possibilities construct a matrix where I cross every unique 25bit member against all other 25bit member where 
in the relation in between it there must be at least 11 common setted bits (only ones, not zeroes).

Let me try to illustrate representing it as binary data, so the first member would be:

```
0000000000111111111111111 (10 zeros and 15 ones) or (15 bits set on 25 bits)
0000000001011111111111111 second member
0000000001101111111111111 third member
0000000001110111111111111 and so on....
...
1111111111111110000000000 up to here. The 3.268.760 member.
```

Now crossing these values over a matrix for the 1 x 1 I must have 15 bits common. Since the result is >= 11 it is a "useful" result.

For the 1 x 2 we have 14 bits common so also a valid result.

Doing that for all members, finally, crossing 1 x 3.268.760 should result in 5 bits common so since it's < 11 its not "useful".

What I need is to find out (by math or algorithm) wich is the minimum number of members needed to cover all possibilities having 11 bits common.

In other words a group of N members that if tested against all others may have at least 11 bits common over the whole 3.268.760 x 3.268.760 universe.

Using a brute force algorithm I found out that with 81 25bit member is possible achive this. But i'm guessing that this number should be smaller (something near 12).

I was trying to use a brute force algorithm to make all possible variations of 12 members over the 3.268.760 but the number of possibilities
it's so huge that it would take more than a hundred years to compute (3,156x10e69 combinations).

I've googled about combinatorics but there are so many fields that i don't know in wich these problem should fit.

So any directions on wich field of combinatorics, or any algorithm for these issue is greatly appreciate.

PS: Just for reference. The "likeness" of two members is calculated using:

```
(Not(a xor b)) and a
```

After that there's a small recursive loop to count the bits given the number of common bits.

**EDIT:** As promissed (@btilly)on the comment below here's the 'fractal' image of the relations [image: Fractal like Relations Matrix] or [link to image](http://universeconquer.webcindario.com/LF.g.s.2012.04.07_025145.png)

The color scale ranges from red (15bits match) to green (11bits match) to black for values smaller than 10bits.

This image is just sample of the 4096 first groups.

Comment: If the order matters shouldn't there be `n!/(n-k)!` combinations?

Comment: I believe this would be better suited to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: GuyGreer refer to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). EDIT: ok misspelling (order doesn't matter). jwodder I agree but since there should be a solution not only using math but also an algorithm, and since I'm more a programmer than mathematician, I prefer to hear people here, ;)

Comment: @PauloBueno: Algorithms are a part of math, and math.SE would be far more likely to have people who actually know about this problem.

Comment: @jwodder Ok replicate the question there. thx.

Comment: I'm guessing that your intuition is based on looking at how many members match a single one, seeing that 10 of those could cover the whole set of members, and figuring that you might need a few more.  Don't think that way.  Instead figure that each element you add to your set matches some fraction of what remains.  On average you'd match 10.5%, your 81 member solution matches about 17%.  That's pretty good!

Comment: @btilly Indeed 81 is nice, using different aproaches i've found even 78. But, by probalistic calculations the theorical optimal number is really near 12. You can prove that by finding that for each single member there are something around 286.000 11bit commom members. Althrought it's not that straightforward since it's more like a giant puzzle. I've emulated a small sample with 7 choose 4 matching 3 and the result is that the minimum number is 4 (not 3 as expected.) Anyway i've ploted the results on an image wich i may post later. It shows a beatiful fractal pattern structure.

Comment: There are indeed 286650 other members that match on exactly 11 bits, and 346126 members (including itself) that match on 11 or more bits.  However after your first few candidates, the rest stop being clumped, and you have a lot of intersections - members that match multiple things in your set.

Comment: By the way this is a "curse of dimensionality" issue.  I'm not surprised that it barely registered with 7 bits.  But 25 bits is likely to be a very different story.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: you want to solve [dominating set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set_problem) on a large, extremely symmetric graph. btilly is right that you should not expect an exact answer. If this were my problem, I would try local search starting with the greedy solution. Pick one set and try to get rid of it by changing the others. This requires data structures to keep track of which sets are covered exactly once.

EDIT: Okay, here's a better idea for a lower bound. For every k from 1 to the value of the optimal solution, there's a lower bound of [25 choose 15] * k / [maximum joint coverage of k sets]. Your bound of 12 (actually 10 by my reckoning, since you forgot some neighbors) corresponds to  k = 1. Proof sketch: fix an arbitrary solution with m sets and consider the most coverage that can be obtained by k of the m. Build a fractional solution where all symmetries of the chosen k are averaged together and scaled so that each element is covered once. The cost of this solution is [25 choose 15] * k / [maximum joint coverage of those k sets], which is at least as large as the lower bound we're shooting for. It's still at least as small, however, as the original m-set solution, as the marginal returns of each set are decreasing.

Computing maximum coverage is in general hard, but there's a factor (e/(e-1))-approximation (≈ 1.58) algorithm: greedy, which it sounds as though you could implement quickly (note: you need to choose the set that covers the most uncovered other sets each time). By multiplying the greedy solution by e/(e-1), we obtain an upper bound on the maximum coverage of k elements, which suffices to power the lower bound described in the previous paragraph.

Warning: if this upper bound is larger than [25 choose 15], then k is too large!

Comment: Actually greedy is not so easy to compute in this case.  If we have a million unmatched elements, it takes a trillion steps to find which is the best next operation.  That's probably not feasible.

Comment: I disagree. On the back of the envelope, it should take about 10 cycles per step to compute and threshold the weight (and, popcnt, cmp), on a 10^9 Hz machine, so that's 10^4 seconds per, or a couple hours. If we run 10^2 of these, that's 10^6 seconds, less than two weeks. I am completely discounting parallelism, both word-level and machine-level, and algorithmic improvements.

Comment: The main algorithmic improvement being to check only the couple hundred thousand neighbors instead of all couple million.

Comment: Just 10 cycles per step?  I have trouble believing that when following a pointer is 5 cycles, a L2 cache hit is 12 cycles, and very few actual instructions are only 1 cycle.  (Figures randomly pulled from http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html.)  With algorithmic improvements it may be doable, and there is a lot of parallelism that can be extracted.  But it isn't simple.

Comment: Well, processors are a bit faster than 1 GHz these days, and by running the computation for a couple candidate sets at a time, the memory access patterns would be nice enough that memory would not be the bottleneck. Nothing you said invalidates my point that this wouldn't be an especially large computational task by the standards of people who use computers to study combinatorial objects, let alone "not feasible".

Comment: I meant feasible for a home hobbyist who is just messing around on their home PC.  You're right that if you are willing to put serious horsepower into it, this solution is well within reach.  And there are possible algorithmic improvements that can make it even more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is extremely hard, you should not expect to be able to find the exact answer.

A greedy solution should produce a "fairly good" answer.  But..how to be greedy?

The idea is to always choose the next element to be the one that is going to match as many possibilities as you can that are currently unmatched.  Unfortunately with over 3 million possible members, that you have to try match against millions of unmatched members (note, your best next guess might already match another member in your candidate set..), even choosing that next element is probably not feasible.

So we'll have to be greedy about choosing the next element.  We will choose each bit to maximize the sum of the probabilities of eventually matching all of the currently unmatched elements.

For that we will need a 2-dimensional lookup table `P` such that `P(n, m)` is the probability that two random members will turn out to have at least 11 bits in common, if `m` of the first `n` bits that are 1 in the first member are also 1 in the second.  This table of 225 probabilities should be precomputed.

This table can easily be computed using the following rules:

1. `P(15, m)` is 0 if `m < 11`, 1 otherwise.
2. For `n < 15`:

   ```
   P(n, m) = P(n+1, m+1) * (15-m) / (25-n) + P(n+1, m) * (10-n+m) / (25-n)
   ```

Now let's start with a few members that are "very far" from each other.  My suggestion would be:

1. First 15 bits 1, rest 0.
2. First 10 bits 0, rest 1.
3. First 8 bits 1, last 7 1, rest 0.
4. Bits 1-4, 9-12, 16-23 are 1, rest 0.

Now starting with your universe of (25 choose 15) members, eliminate all of those that match one of the elements in your initial collection.

Next we go into the heart of the algorithm.

```
While there are unmatched members:
    Find the bit that appears in the most unmatched members (break ties randomly)
    Make that the first set bit of our candidate member for the group.
    While the candidate member has less than 15 set bits:
        Let p_best = 0, bit_best = 0;
        For each unset bit:
            Let p = 0
            For each unmatched member:
                p += P(n, m) where m = number of bits in common between
                             candidate member+this bit and the unmatched member
                             and n = bits in candidate member + 1
            If p_best < p:
                p_best = p
                bit_best = this unset bit
        Set bit_best as the next bit in our candidate member.
    Add the candidate member to our collection
    Remove all unmatched members that match this from unmatched members
The list of candidate members is our answer
```

I have not written code, I therefore have no idea how good an answer this algorithm will produce.  But assuming that it does no better than your current, for 77 candidate members (we cheated and started with 4) you have to make 271 passes through your unmatched candidates (25 to find the first bit, 24 to find the second, etc down to 11 to find the 15th, and one more to remove the matched members).  That's 20867 passes.  If you have an average of 1 million unmatched members, that's on the order of a 20 billion operations.

This won't be quick.  But it should be computationally feasible.

Comment: The greedy solution is somewhat near my linear forward/backward brute force algorithm since I start scanning each member and comparing agains my group. If the test fails this member is included in the group. Resulting in 82 when starting from 1 to 3mi. And 81 when doing it backwards.

Comment: The problem is that the element you look at is always very similar to elements already covered by your group, you want to add elements that look different.  If you don't want to try my complicated greedy algorithm, instead try jumping around by a different amount, for a random example jump forward 685,319 (wrapping at 3,268,760) each time.  I expect that you'll improve your answer.  (Though not as much as greedy would.)